# Model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name' - Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I receive the following error message when i post a new party: **Party model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'** and it points to the code in my parties_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @party = Party.new(party_params)
```

Im struggling to understand the reason for this error,

Here is the other code i'm working with

**party.rb**

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :image, presence: true
    end
```

**parties_controller.rb**

```
class PartiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_party, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /parties
  # GET /parties.json
  def index
    @parties = Party.all
  end
  # GET /parties/1
  # GET /parties/1.json
  def show
  end
  # GET /parties/new
  def new
    @party = Party.new
  end
  # GET /parties/1/edit
  def edit
  end
  # POST /parties
  # POST /parties.json
  def create
    @party = Party.new(party_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @party.save
        format.html { redirect_to @party, notice: 'Party was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @party }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @party.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # PATCH/PUT /parties/1
  # PATCH/PUT /parties/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @party.update(party_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @party, notice: 'Party was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @party }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @party.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # DELETE /parties/1
  # DELETE /parties/1.json
  def destroy
    @party.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to parties_url, notice: 'Party was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_party
      @party = Party.find(params[:id])
    end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def party_params
      params.require(:party).permit(:latitude, :longitude, :address, :description, :title, :image)
    end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :parties

  validates :name, presence: true
  #validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+edu)\z/ }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because there are duplicate migration files created in the db/migrations file. What you need to do is delete all these files then on your terminal do a rake db:rollback to cancel all migrations. then do a rails d paperclip MODEL(replace name with model u r using) image. 
Then do a rails g paperclip MODEL image then rake db:migrate. it should work now

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `image_file_name` should not be an `attr_accessor` - it should be an actual attribute of your `party` object (`@party.image_file_name`)

Considering you have performed the required [`migrations`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#migrations) to set up your `db` with Paperclip, I believe the problem will likely be with this line:

```
validates :image, presence: true
```

I believe you'll be better using the inbuilt Paperclip [`AttachmentPresenceValidator`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#validations) like so:

```
   class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
        validates_attachment_presence :image
    end
```

The reason for this is that when you pass the `image` object to your `Party` model, you're not sending the "naked" object. Paperclip assigns various attributes to the object before it passes, which is why you're seeing the `attr_accessor` error (Paperclip assigns the attributes before it saves, so it has to use `attr_accessor` to create them)

Using the inbuilt `validates_attachment` methods will give you the ability to validate the `Paperclip` object directly

Comment: Hi @RichPeck, I entered the code: has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
        validates_attachment_presence :image into the party model, but receive the same error as before

Comment: Okay this could be caused by several issues. Do you have the latest version of Paperclip? If not, upgrade. Also, have you migrated to give your tables the required columns?