# Rails 4: Paperclip Error Post model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, paperclip, attr-accessor

First, let me specify that I did find two questions on Stack Overflow that are very similar to my problem:

- [Model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name' - Ruby on Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588379/model-missing-required-attr-accessor-for-image-file-name-ruby-on-rails-4)
- [Paperclip Error: model missing required attr_accessor for 'avatar_file_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746393/paperclip-error-model-missing-required-attr-accessor-for-avatar-file-name)

However, I am not sure the issue is the same.

Let me explain.

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many: :posts
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

The `Post` model has the following attributes:

```
references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
date :date
time :time
string :subject
string :format
text :copy
attachment :image
```

and the `attachment` was setup as follows with Paperclip in Post model:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "64x64", med: "100x100", large: "200x200" }
validates_attachment :image, :content_type => { :content_type => "image/png" },
                                :size => { :in => 0..3000.kilobytes }
```

Here is the migration I used:

```
class AddPaperclipToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :posts, :media
    add_attachment :posts, :image

  end
end
```

**Note**: `remove_column :posts, :media` is here because I used to have a simple attribute named "media" before I installed Paperclip. This was a not a functionning file field, but a fake placeholder I used to modelize my table and have it appear in my UI.

—————

**UPDATE**: I checked my schema.rb file and the migration did go through, since I get the following Post table:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "calendar_id"
  t.date     "date"
  t.time     "time"
  t.string   "subject"
  t.string   "format"
  t.text     "copy"
  t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  t.string   "image_file_name"
  t.string   "image_content_type"
  t.integer  "image_file_size"
  t.datetime "image_updated_at"
end
```

—————

Here is what I don't understand:

— *When I run the app locally:* everything works fine, I can create a new post, upload a file, save the post and then see it in the post show view.

— *When I deploy to Heroku:* I can create a new post and upload a file, but when I try to save it, I get the error message `We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.`

So, I got and check the logs, and get the following info:

```
2015-10-06T15:16:00.867374+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/calendars" for 24.205.62.204 at 2015-10-06 15:16:00 +0000
2015-10-06T15:16:00.874619+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-10-06T15:16:00.886324+00:00 app[web.1]:   Administration Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "administrations".* FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."calendar_id" = $1 AND "administrations"."user_id" = $2  ORDER BY "administrations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["calendar_id", 1], ["user_id", 1]]
2015-10-06T15:16:00.889529+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered calendars/index.html.erb within layouts/calendars (11.8ms)
2015-10-06T15:16:00.871085+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CalendarsController#index as HTML
2015-10-06T15:16:00.880653+00:00 app[web.1]:   Calendar Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "calendars".* FROM "calendars" INNER JOIN "administrations" ON "calendars"."id" = "administrations"."calendar_id" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
2015-10-06T15:16:00.888807+00:00 app[web.1]:   Administration Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "administrations".* FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND "administrations"."calendar_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["calendar_id", 1]]
2015-10-06T15:16:00.890698+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 10.1ms | ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
2015-10-06T15:16:00.894553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/calendars" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=84199c51-e02b-43a1-8bf8-ac14b102146d fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=2728
2015-10-06T15:16:02.887552+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/calendars/1" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=3ebd4dd2-ecad-4bef-8bdc-ac3f61a807ac fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=66ms status=200 bytes=8538
2015-10-06T15:16:02.826123+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/calendars/1" for 24.205.62.204 at 2015-10-06 15:16:02 +0000
2015-10-06T15:16:02.858126+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Exists (3.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."calendar_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["calendar_id", 1]]
2015-10-06T15:16:02.834055+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-10-06T15:16:02.883375+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 37.0ms | ActiveRecord: 8.3ms)
2015-10-06T15:16:02.828856+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CalendarsController#show as HTML
2015-10-06T15:16:02.828863+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2015-10-06T15:16:02.839230+00:00 app[web.1]:   Calendar Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" INNER JOIN "administrations" ON "calendars"."id" = "administrations"."calendar_id" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND "calendars"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 1]]
2015-10-06T15:16:02.831152+00:00 app[web.1]:   Calendar Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-10-06T15:16:02.877428+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered calendars/show.html.erb within layouts/calendars (34.0ms)
2015-10-06T15:16:44.490246+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/calendars/1/posts" for 24.205.62.204 at 2015-10-06 15:16:44 +0000
2015-10-06T15:16:44.498537+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.2ms)  BEGIN
2015-10-06T15:16:44.501575+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
2015-10-06T15:16:44.493243+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"j7RmblwHH2Aj0JCUrYKhAvVvdIDiSOY7DO07NbJNQM/OEsDzA70+jTABthyPO7/oZhCgb8+E/0DRhPdxO5WXIQ==", "post"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2015", "date(2i)"=>"10", "date(3i)"=>"6", "time(1i)"=>"2015", "time(2i)"=>"10", "time(3i)"=>"6", "time(4i)"=>"15", "time(5i)"=>"16", "subject"=>"Launch", "format"=>"Image", "copy"=>"Hey, Calendy is launching, take a look here!", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc6b1a6aa20 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151006-6-ljl7ny.png>, @original_filename="calendy-social-media-calendar-tool-collaboration.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"calendy-social-media-calendar-tool-collaboration.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Post", "calendar_id"=>"1"}
2015-10-06T15:16:44.502893+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-06T15:16:44.501140+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
2015-10-06T15:16:44.495949+00:00 app[web.1]:   Calendar Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-10-06T15:16:44.493113+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
2015-10-06T15:16:44.502896+00:00 app[web.1]: Paperclip::Error (Post model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'):
2015-10-06T15:16:44.502898+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:30:in `create'
2015-10-06T15:16:44.502900+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-06T15:16:44.502901+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-06T15:16:44.784398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=46565200-4c91-4251-9bc3-bf8167c515c8 fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=93
2015-10-06T15:16:44.505034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/calendars/1/posts" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=214a9ce9-deca-4ef1-954a-08b741c712fe fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=129ms status=500 bytes=1714
updating Heroku CLI...done. Updated to 3.42.15
```

The line `Paperclip::Error (Post model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'):` seems to be the problem, which I don't understand, since I have the following line in my `posts_controller`:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:date, :time, :subject, :format, :copy, :image)
end
```

as recommended in the [Paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#usage).

Should I also authorize all Paperclip attributes, ie:

- `image_file_name`
- `image_file_size`
- `image_content_type`
- `image_updated_at`

Or is it a problem of migrations, as it seems to be in the other two Stack Overflo questions I mentioned in reference at the beginning of this question?

Comment: since everything is working fine on your local machine but not in `Heroku`, I can advise you to go and check the `schema.rb` that exist on `Heroku` and make sure that `posts table` has all the `attributes`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how/where can I check this file?

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953390/how-to-view-current-database-schema-for-heroku-app-in-terminal)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very useful, I learnt a new command today. When I run `heroku run "bundle exec rake db:schema:dump && cat db/schema.rb"` I get the same DB schema as on my local machine. So this is not causing the issue. But Adrian Mann's answer fixed the problem. Thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:date, :time, :subject, :format, :copy, image: [:image_file_name, :image_file_size, :image_content_type, :image_updated_at])
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to implement this, but for some reason, I am now getting a H10 error on Heroku. So I am going to keep trying until I fix everything and will let you know how your solution is doing for my problem.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Just for information, my H10 error was coming from a typo in the `params_require` line, as I had two `)` at the end of the line. Just a dumb copy/paste mistake. Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer. I believe this could help other people using Paperclip.